# Cookie Munging in Asp .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I googled a lot but did'nt found any good stuff which explains cookie munging.
I know that cookie munging is used in scuh situations when

- Some browsers do not support cookies.
- Sometimes users disable cookies in the browser.

but i had little confusions regarding to it. I want to know how internally it works and how it is used in Asp .Net MVC. Also is there any limitatons with it and any alternative for cookie munging.
Please suggest me a better link to understand it briefly.
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.justskins.com/forums/cookie-munging-problem-125900.html#

Comment: Change your question title to Cookie Munging in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC was designed not to support cookieless sessions. As per msdn 
*"ASP.NET MVC does not support cookieless session and authentication and we actively discourage it"*
See [this.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx#Cookieless)

So what option you have now is to implement authentication by passing an session_id in url of every secure controller, here is what you can do :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Secure",
            url: "{session_id}/{controller}/{action}"
            defaults: new 
            { 
                session_id=string.Empty,
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index"
            }
        );
    }
```

Now when user logs in with username/password redirect him to urls with session_id like 
//controller/action ,you can build sessionid like "username|expirytime" and encrypt it so that on decryption you get username and check for session is expired or not. Or you can store in database with schema like 'session_id','userid',expirytime'

Now you need one more things that is action filter

```
public class SessionIdFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var sessionid = filterContext.RouteData.Values["session_id"]; 
        //Check session id against db , if exists return;
                   filterContext.HttpContext.User= new CustomPrincipal("username");//read about custom IPrincipal implementation its easy. 

    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    { 
       if( !filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
          { 
             filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(loginurl); 
          }
    }
}
```

I hope that can get you started,you might need to make some tweak on how you form your urls 'ActionLinks' with {session_id} param.

**But yes session hijacks are possible in this case too.**

Answer (score 0):

By default, asp.net uses cookies to store session id for the logged in user. But there is an option in every browser to disable cookies. If cookies are disabled, then any website will not be able to create cookies on user's machine.

When cookies are disabled, then session Id is gets appended in the URL and passed to the server. Server decodes it and fulfill the requested page.

Refer to this [link](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/55395-COOKIE-MUNGING.aspx) and this [document](https://ankitnandekar.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/cookies.docx) for more information.